# Spark Error: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes

Tags: scala, out-of-memory, apache-spark, rdd

When I run a Spark job using its example code BinaryClassification.scala with my own data, it always shows the errors like "Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.".

I set the memory to 4G via conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"BinaryClassification with $params").set("spark.executor.memory", "4g"), and it doesn't work. Does anyone get any ideas? Thank you:)

I run it locally on a Macbook Pro with 16GB ram.

```
bin/spark-submit --class BinaryClassification ~/dev/scalaworkspace/BinaryClassification/BinaryClassification_fat.jar ~/data/trajectory.libsvm --algorithm LR

Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: wangchao,
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: wangchao,
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(wangchao, ); users with modify permissions: Set(wangchao, )
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@wangchaos-mbp-2.lan:65405]
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@wangchaos-mbp-2.lan:65405]
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 65405.
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /var/folders/6k/nww6s1p52yg424zdcckvpwvc0000gn/T/spark-local-20141122170724-b202
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port 65406.
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 65406 with id = ConnectionManagerId(wangchaos-mbp-2.lan,65406)
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager wangchaos-mbp-2.lan:65406 with 265.1 MB RAM
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /var/folders/6k/nww6s1p52yg424zdcckvpwvc0000gn/T/spark-cf2b6d19-1db6-4e66-b080-8558a281cd50
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 65407.
14/11/22 17:07:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
14/11/22 17:07:25 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://wangchaos-mbp-2.lan:4040
14/11/22 17:07:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/11/22 17:07:25 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/wangchao/dev/scalaworkspace/BinaryClassification/BinaryClassification_fat.jar at http://192.168.199.120:65407/jars/BinaryClassification_fat.jar with timestamp 1416647245419
14/11/22 17:07:25 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@wangchaos-mbp-2.lan:65405/user/HeartbeatReceiver
14/11/22 17:07:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 238168618 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_0 in memory! Free memory is 238168618 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:30 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 238168618 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:30 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 238168618 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_1 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_3 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_0 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_0 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_0 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_2 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:32 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 166721050 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_1 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_1 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_2 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:35 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_2 in memory! Free memory is 158787330 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_3 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_3 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_0 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_6_0 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_0 in memory! Free memory is 158791130 bytes.
Training: 385580, test: 96120.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:41 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72899530 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:45 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:45 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72905066 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:47 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
14/11/22 17:07:47 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:48 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72900010 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:52 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:52 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72892226 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:59 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:07:59 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:09 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:09 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:16 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:16 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:19 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:22 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:22 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:22 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:22 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:23 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:23 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:26 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72882858 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72882858 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72882858 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:29 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72882858 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:30 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:30 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:33 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:36 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:37 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:37 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:40 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:43 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:43 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:43 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:43 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:44 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:47 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:51 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:54 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72893082 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72885298 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:08:58 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:01 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:01 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:01 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:01 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:02 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:05 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72887738 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:08 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:09 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:09 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72903306 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_2 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_3 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:12 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_7_1 in memory! Free memory is 72895522 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_1 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_1 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_1 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_3 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_3 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_4_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_3 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
14/11/22 17:09:15 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_8_2 in memory! Free memory is 58905314 bytes.
Test areaUnderPR = 0.8666401497180547.
Test areaUnderROC = 0.7099423688872086.
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. How many nodes you've in the clustet?

Comment: I run it locally on a Macbook Pro with 16GB ram.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently you are running with the default memory options, like indicated in the logs:

```
14/11/22 17:07:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
```

If you are running locally, you need to set the option `--driver-memory 4G` instead.

Comment: How can I make it default 2g?